# My camera doing weird thing

Tags: 3d-view, camera

So I opened my project and noticed something that wasn't there last time I saved, I don't really know how to describe it so I couldn't find any solutions on the internet. I also tried looking in some camera settings and trying turn on and off some options but nothing happened. Also it happens only in solid mode, other modes view it as normal.

Im Pretty sure it is somehow related to Render region function because it happened in the exact spot I put it, here's a picture. [image]

Comment: It looks like this: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html
May be the Ctrl+Alt+B fix it.

Comment: Already solved, Alt + B helped which is strange because it didn't work before

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.